# jmeter slow response times

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have set up a test plan using Apache JMeter, but when testing a remote server I am seeing much slower times than it takes the browser to run the same test, it's on order of 5-10x slower. For example chrome takes about 300ms to load a simple static page with some embedded assets while jmeter reports 2000+ms for the same page from the same machine.

I've tried tweaking the thread count to make sure this is not the bottleneck as well as not too much load slowing down the server, but nothing seems to change these slow numbers.

What else can I look at to get more realistic response times out of this tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this one out, the issue was that "Retrieve all embedded resources" was checked, which I want, but I was also not using the "concurrent pool size" option, so it was cycling through each of the ~10 embedded HTTP requests on the page serially and reporting slow overall load times. Checking this and adding a realistic browser concurrency number (Chrome uses 6 these days so that's what I went with: http://sgdev-blog.blogspot.com/2014/01/maximum-concurrent-connection-to-same.html)
give me numbers that are very close to real browser testing.

Comment: Turning off "Retrieve all embedded resources" is what fixed this for me. You can do this by going to HTTP Request Defaults > Advanced and uncheck the option. Before doing this, JMeter kept throwing an OutOfMemoryError. Now I am running lots of test users quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) as browsers download embedded stuff like images, scripts, styles, etc. but do it **only once**, on subsequent requests aforementioned resources are being returned from browser's cache, no actual request is being made.

See [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743654-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide for other recommendations on how to make your JMeter test more realistic.

Comment: Yeah already looked into that, I'm more interested in peaky traffic that will not typically be cached so it wasn't super helpful, but the embedded request was a killer.